# Bean Validation applied on interface type

Tags: java, validation, generics, bean-validation

The question is very short:

Let's consider there is the following class:

```
public class someClass implements someInterface {
    @NotNull
    String someString;

    // ... some cool logic, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

And this interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    // cool stuff
}
```

Somewhere else is this method:

```
public <T extends SomeInterface> T doStuff (T someInterface) {
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violatons = validator.validate();
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    return someInterface;
}
```

I don't have much experience with BV. Will someString in SomeClass be validated or do I need to cast someInterface to SomeClass explicitly?

The scenario here is simplified. In reality I have different generic Classes and interfaces and it would mean *a little* bit of work. That's why I'm asking carefully.

Hope there's one of those experts hangin around!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to cast it explicitly. It would be done for you.

Comment: So if I validate a freely chosen interface the implementing class will always be validated as expected?

Comment: Yes, you can't validate an interface, you can only validate an implementation. The instance you have is the implementation of the interface, not the interface itself. The interface can't exist on its own anyway. Just try it and see.

Comment: Thank you, I was a little confused. I know interfaces cannot exist on their own. I was wondering how BV would react to a given interface impl. But if you think about it a moment it is obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bean Validation will obtain the constraints from the actual type of the validated instance, i.e. you can pass a variable of the interface type and Bean Validation will consider the constraints from the implementation (constraints declared on super-types and interfaces apply as well).

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I've been asking myself after reading babas comments. Whether constraints defined on interfaces apply instead of those inside the imolementation. Now I'm smarter.