# How to use validation for interface DTO (not class DTO) in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

So I'm trying to validate tableId's pattern (only accept number), min (cannot < 0) to return a message in Spring boot, but all the guides I've found are using annotation on a class DTO, not an interface DTO.

Here's my interface DTO:

```
public interface BillChargingListDTO {
    public Integer getBillId();
    public Integer getUserId();
    public Integer getTableId();
    public Double getSum();
}
```

So how can I validate it? I'm expecting someone to answer for it, thank you.

Comment: Here you can't instantiate an Interface. My guess is that you will have to provide an implementation and then apply validation rules there.

Comment: @HarryCoder so do I have to change the data type in Controller or Service? As the methods return a ResponseEntity<List<BillChargingListDTO>>.

Comment: This link can give you more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522758/bean-validation-applied-on-interface-type

Comment: Provide more details

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov I'm validating `tableId` to return a custom message on Postman, but the only thing I get are the default ones like error 500, or 400.

Comment: @HarryCoder I have another problem, the error message didn't appear in Postman, but only on console. I have used a custom handler to catch it, and then the program didn't return any messages.

Comment: @Colony provide more details

Comment: @HarryCoder This is the method:
`@GetMapping("/sales/bill-charging/{tableId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<BillChargingListDTO>> getBillChargingByTableId(@Valid TableIdDTO tableIdDTO) {
        List<BillChargingListDTO> billChargingList = billChargingService.getAllBillCharging(tableIdDTO.getTableId());
        if (billChargingList.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(billChargingList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }`
In Postman, it didn't return the message but the console did.

Comment: @Colony update your question. It is not clear in the comments.